# Writing a "system" of equations in Rmarkdown with LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm wondering how to write a "system" of equations like the one below in a file.Rmd.

[image]

In Texmaker I use a newcommand to write it; maybe this is not possible in a notebook R.

Comment: In Rmarkdown, you can use `$$` to delimit LaTex.  So, for example, `$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a} \\ 0 \end{cases} $$` gives you the basic format you're looking for.  `\begin{cases}` and `\end{cases}` gives you the opening curly brace and `\\ ` separates the different cases.  You should be able to fill in the blanks from here.

Comment: Could you please provide a glimpse of your try?